# How to add data-attributes with no value to elements

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation, custom-data-attribute

I want to use jQuery to create Foundation alert boxes (docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html)).

The alert box div takes a `data-alert`, attribute as in:

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box">
```

I know you can add attributes to elements using `.attr()`, `.data()`, `.prop()`, etc., but how can I add something like `data-alert`, an attribute that doesn't have a value?

Comment: have you tried data-alert=""?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With jQuery, you would just set it to an empty string:

```
$('.alert-box').attr('data-alert','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you can set `<div data-alert="" class="alert-box"></div>`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ff8px/

Comment: This doesn't add a data attribute